# think vs think of

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> My mind's not working , I can't think of anything at the moment.

Vs

> My mind's not working, I can't think at the moment .

Which one is grammatically correct in context ?

Comment: think of some thing in response to someone versus just think. But you probably mean: I can't think about anything at the moment.

Comment: The question is, think vs. think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are incorrect on one point — they are run-on sentences.  Let me give you some ways you can correct that first.

> My mind's not working, so I can't think of anything at the moment.

If your mind isn't working, it is logical that you aren't capable of thinking and therefore "so" works well in this sentence.

> My mind's not working ... I can't think of anything at the moment.

The use of an ellipsis here implies that there's a pause.  You're really trying to think of something, but even after trying for a few seconds you just can't do it.

Both of these revisions could be applied to your second sentence.  Other revisions could be made, but for the sake of simplicity, I'll leave it at that.  (Also note that I removed the space between the word "working" and the comma.)

Now, as far as usage goes.  It looks as if the first sentence — the one I used in the examples above is more common than the second one you listed.  Here are some examples I found from publications:

> "I wish I could do something to help, but **I can't think of anything at the moment** that would make things better ...
>   —[***A Box of Dreams: The Collected Dream Series, Books 1-5***](https://books.google.com/books?id=RhxFBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT248&dq=%22can't+think+of+anything+at+the+moment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLg8Cq_q3ZAhVY7WMKHbhxAHUQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22can't%20think%20of%20anything%20at%20the%20moment%22&f=false)
>
> "Of course, **I can't think of anything at the moment,** the brain is too stuffed-up.
>   —From a blog post titled, [**"Writing Excerpts – April 25, 2016,"**](https://www.fillingthejars.com/2016/04/25/writing-excerpts-april-25-2016/) *Filling the Jars*
>
> "I have to think about what I can do. Only **I can't think at the moment.**
>   —[***Four-Leaf Clover***](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qh45AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT88&dq=%22I+can't+think+at+the+moment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL2dHcgq7ZAhUY_WMKHUpGAwwQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22I%20can't%20think%20at%20the%20moment%22&f=false)

I would consider all of those grammatically correct uses of the phrases in question.

---

As for run-on sentences, or comma splices, (or whatever you prefer to call them), you'll find several web pages on the topic.  If you need more help with this, the page connected to the link below is probably one of the simplest, yet thorough, pages I've found on the subject:

[**What Are Run-On Sentences?**](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/what-are-run-on-sentences)

Comment: The question is, think vs think of